# Problem combining FastAPI dependency and Strawberry GraphQL context

Tags: dependency-injection, fastapi, strawberry-graphql

I am struggling to get a certain type of dependency to work with FastAPI and Strawberry GraphQL, specifically with establishing a context.  My service contains both a GraphQL route and other types of routes and the following works just fine:

```
@router.get("/identity", response_model=str)
async def user(user_info: str = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return user_info
```

but on my GraphQL side, I have

```
async def get_context(user=Depends(get_current_user())):
    log.info(user)
    return {"user": user}

graphql_app = GraphQLRouter(schema, graphiql=True, context_getter=get_context)
```

when I test this, `get_current_user()` is not getting invoked, and the value of `user` is output in the above logging as `<inspect._empty object at ...>`.

Why would the dependency not get handled in this case?

Comment: Please reach https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1279 for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like in your definition of `get_context`, you are calling `get_current_user`, but in `Depends`, you must pass the function itself, not its return value (you're doing this correctly in your `user` function). Changing your function definition to

```py
async def get_context(user=Depends(get_current_user)):
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Duh on my part; thanks for pointing that out!